# Performance impact of mvcc, vector clocks, locks?

Tags: concurrency, nosql, locking, mvcc

NoSql dbs use either mvcc (e.g Voldemort) , vector clocks (e.g Riak) or locks on fiels (Redis).

What are the advantages and disandvantages of the types?
And what impact does those methods have on the performance on writes? / reads?